# How to change flowScope object from view model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have a subflow, where i defined var, like

```
 <var name="tarrifOffer" class="ru.example.TariffOffer" />
```

Now i have three view states and i want to change this variable in first state and send it into third state. But when i'm in third view- state it's comming null. How to save state of object in all views?

I tried change scopes of variable and take value from RequestContextHolder, but state, that i changed in 1st form didn't save in 3rd state. I cute all code what don't need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="tarrifOffer" class="ru.example.TariffOffer" />
    <view-state id="1" view="1/1/1" >
        <on-render>
            <set name="tarrifOffer" value="tarrifOffer"/>
        </on-render>
        <transition on="addPhone" to="2"/>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="2" view="2/2">
        <transition on="returnToForm" to="3"/>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="3" view="3/3/3" >
        <on-entry>
             <set name="tarrifOffer" value="tarrifOffer"/>
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="next" to="endSubFlow"/>
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="endSubFlow"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the var outside any of the states, it will be in flow scope, available to all of them. You'd typically be accessing fields of that object, rather than creating new instances of it in each state.